# TypeError: Vonage is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, vonage

I'm trying to send an SMS message to a random phone number from a node js file. I'm using my Vonage account. When I try this from the web page of the Vonage (https://dashboard.nexmo.com/getting-started/sms), it works perfectly. But when I run the code they suggest, it doesn't work anymore and I get this error: TypeError: Vonage is not a constructor+
After I installed the package (npm install @vonage/server-sdk), I created a js file with this code:

```
const Vonage = require('@vonage/server-sdk')

const vonage = new Vonage({
  apiKey: "27945288",
  apiSecret: "************Ek95"
})

const from = "Vonage APIs"
const to = "*********13"
const text = 'A text message sent using the Vonage SMS API'

async function sendSMS() {
    await vonage.sms.send({to, from, text})
        .then(resp => { console.log('Message sent successfully'); console.log(resp); })
        .catch(err => { console.log('There was an error sending the messages.'); console.error(err); });
}

sendSMS();
```

I run it with: "node sendSMS.js"

Answer (score 1):

It has to be

```
const { Vonage } = require('@vonage/server-sdk')
```

not

```
const Vonage = require('@vonage/server-sdk')
```

Answer (score 0):

In your package.json make sure you are using Vonage version 3 not 2. Version 2 doesn't support this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the library with the correct ES6 syntax.

From :

```
const Vonage = require('@vonage/server-sdk')
```

To:

```
import { Vonage } from "@vonage/server-sdk"
```